# Stop text moving when border change width

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am facing a really annoying problem ^^. My left menu text is moving when the border is expanded with jquery. I am trying everything to stop moving the text. but nothing works :/
Any idea ?

CSS for left menu?

```
.main .left {
    width: 220px; 
    margin-right: 20px; 
    float: left;
}
.main .box {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.main .box .bname {
    font-size: 15px; 
    background: url(../images/sepa.png) no-repeat left center; 
    padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}
.main .box ul {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;
}
.main .box ul li {
    padding-left: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
}
.main .box ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 3px;
}

.main .box ul li a:hover{}
```

My jquery for animated border:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".box ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({borderWidth: 20}, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({borderWidth: 2}, "fast");
        });
});
```

The problem is when the border animate ( borderWidth: 20 ) it will move text to the right. I want the text fixed on the same place.
my html:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="nadpis">Dokumenty</div>
   <ul>
       {foreach $MENU['USER1'] as $row}
           <li>
               <a href="{!$row->odkaz}" {widget  rsLista 'MENU',$row->idecko,$MENU_WEB['USER1'],$MENU_SLOZKA['USER1'],$row->nazev}>{$row->nazev}</a>
           </li>  
       {/foreach}
   </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: And please provide your menu html

Comment: What are you expecting the text to do when the border expands? If it doesn't move the border will overlap it surely?

Comment: try counter-animating the margin. but without the HTML, it's hard to tell if this would cause trouble.

Comment: what i am expecting with the text is to stay in the same place. not moving to right

Comment: Try putting some padding on the element, and then when you want to increase the width of the border, reduce the padding at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the text by manipulating element padding and making it part of the animation:

CSS

```
.main .box ul li{padding:18px; margin-bottom: 1px;}
```

JS

```
$(".box ul li").hover(function() {
   $(this).animate({borderWidth: 20, padding:2}, "fast");
 }, function() {
   $(this).animate({borderWidth: 2, padding:18}, "fast");
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/6VjCr/